# i am using ng-grid who loads a data from a json file , i want to make edit and delete buttons to edit and delete my data , using angular js?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

i have already created an edit button but when i click on the button and edit my data it doesnt gets reflected into the row it hides the previous data , i want to implement a functionality which enables me to edit the data which is previously held in the row , and show and reflect the changes done by me into row on click of  edit button again

here is my code main.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.filterOptions = {
        filterText: "",
        useExternalFilter: true
    };

    $scope.totalServerItems = 0;
    $scope.pagingOptions = {
        pageSizes: [5, 10, 20],
        pageSize: 5,
        currentPage: 1
    };
    $scope.setPagingData = function(data, page, pageSize){
        var pagedData = data.slice((page - 1) * pageSize, page * pageSize);
        $scope.myData = pagedData;
        $scope.totalServerItems = data.length;
        if (!$scope.$$phase) {
            $scope.$apply();
        }
    };
    $scope.getPagedDataAsync = function (pageSize, page, searchText) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var data;
            if (searchText) {
                var ft = searchText.toLowerCase();
                $http.get('largeLoad.json').success(function (largeLoad) {
                    data = largeLoad.filter(function(item) {
                        return JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().indexOf(ft) != -1;
                    });
                    $scope.setPagingData(data,page,pageSize);
                });
            } else {
                $http.get('largeLoad.json').success(function (largeLoad) {
                    $scope.setPagingData(largeLoad,page,pageSize);
                });
            }
        }, 100);
    };

    $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage);

    $scope.$watch('pagingOptions', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal !== oldVal && newVal.currentPage !== oldVal.currentPage) {
            $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage, $scope.filterOptions.filterText);
        }
    }, true);
    $scope.$watch('filterOptions', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal !== oldVal) {
            $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage, $scope.filterOptions.filterText);
        }
    }, true);

    $scope.edit = function (row) {
        row.entity.edit = !row.entity.edit;
    };

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'myData',
        enableRowSelection: false,
        enablePaging: true,
        showFooter: true,
        totalServerItems:'totalServerItems',
        pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,
        filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions,
        columnDefs: [{
            field: 'nm',
            displayName: 'Name',
            cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText"><div ng-show="!row.entity.edit">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div>' +
            '<div ng-show="row.entity.edit" class="ngCellText"><input type="text" ng-model="row.entity.name"/></div></div>'
        },
            {
            field: 'cty',
            displayName: 'city',
            cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText"><div ng-show="!row.entity.edit">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div>' +
            '<div ng-show="row.entity.edit" class="ngCellText"><input type="text" ng-model="row.entity.city"/></div></div>'
        },
            {
            field: 'hse',
            displayName: 'Address',
            cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText"><div ng-show="!row.entity.edit">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div>' +
            '<div ng-show="row.entity.edit" class="ngCellText"><input type="text" ng-model="row.entity.Address"/></div></div>'
            },

            {
                field: 'yrs',
                displayName: 'PinCode',
                cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText"><div ng-show="!row.entity.edit">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div>' +
                '<div ng-show="row.entity.edit" class="ngCellText"><input type="text" ng-model="row.entity.PinCode"/></div></div>'
            },
         {
            displayName: 'Edit',
            cellTemplate: '<button id="editBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="edit(row)" >Modify</button> '

        }]
    };
```

});

you can see it on plunker below is the link

http://plnkr.co/edit/QbsQ6uDgNxts9TUMERj2?p=preview

Comment: Where you write code to save data and render it to grid?

Comment: i have a json file from where i am taking the data

Answer (score 0):

You are not really saving the Data anywhere , what i can see in you js file is that you are just making the row Editable and Non-Editable on the Click of your button

```
row.entity.edit = !row.entity.edit;
```

add some code to save the data into the entities or try this

http://brianhann.com/create-a-modal-row-editor-for-ui-grid-in-minutes/

, that will solve your issue

Comment: ya i have to just make it editable and non editable on the click of the button only as i am playing with the dummy data , the problem i am facing is that when my row becomes editable it becomes blank , i just want that it should show my data soo tht i can edit it and it should show my reflected changes also for that mean time

Answer (score 0):

in your fiddle change your main.js to the follownig (i changed ng-model)

in grid definition

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.filterOptions = {
        filterText: "",
        useExternalFilter: true
    };

    $scope.totalServerItems = 0;
    $scope.pagingOptions = {
        pageSizes: [5, 10, 20],
        pageSize: 5,
        currentPage: 1
    };
    $scope.setPagingData = function(data, page, pageSize){
        var pagedData = data.slice((page - 1) * pageSize, page * pageSize);
        $scope.myData = pagedData;
        $scope.totalServerItems = data.length;
        if (!$scope.$$phase) {
            $scope.$apply();
        }
    };
    $scope.getPagedDataAsync = function (pageSize, page, searchText) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var data;
            if (searchText) {
                var ft = searchText.toLowerCase();
                $http.get('largeLoad.json').success(function (largeLoad) {
                    data = largeLoad.filter(function(item) {
                        return JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().indexOf(ft) != -1;
                    });
                    $scope.setPagingData(data,page,pageSize);
                });
            } else {
                $http.get('largeLoad.json').success(function (largeLoad) {
                    $scope.setPagingData(largeLoad,page,pageSize);
                });
            }
        }, 100);
    };

    $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage);

    $scope.$watch('pagingOptions', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal !== oldVal && newVal.currentPage !== oldVal.currentPage) {
            $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage, $scope.filterOptions.filterText);
        }
    }, true);
    $scope.$watch('filterOptions', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal !== oldVal) {
            $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage, $scope.filterOptions.filterText);
        }
    }, true);

    $scope.edit = function (row) {
        row.entity.edit = !row.entity.edit;
    };

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'myData',
        enableRowSelection: false,
        enablePaging: true,
        showFooter: true,
        totalServerItems:'totalServerItems',
        pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,
        filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions,
        columnDefs: [{
            field: 'nm',
            displayName: 'Name',
            cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText"><div ng-show="!row.entity.edit">{{row.entity.nm}}</div>' +
            '<div ng-show="row.entity.edit" class="ngCellText"><input type="text" ng-model="row.entity.nm"/></div></div>'
        },
            {
            field: 'cty',
            displayName: 'city',
            cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText"><div ng-show="!row.entity.edit">{{row.entity.cty}}</div>' +
            '<div ng-show="row.entity.edit" class="ngCellText"><input type="text" ng-model="row.entity.cty"/></div></div>'
        },
            {
            field: 'hse',
            displayName: 'Address',
            cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText"><div ng-show="!row.entity.edit">{{row.entity.hse}}</div>' +
            '<div ng-show="row.entity.edit" class="ngCellText"><input type="text" ng-model="row.entity.hse"/></div></div>'
            },

            {
                field: 'yrs',
                displayName: 'PinCode',
                cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText"><div ng-show="!row.entity.edit">{{row.entity.yrs}}</div>' +
                '<div ng-show="row.entity.edit" class="ngCellText"><input type="text" ng-model="row.entity.yrs"/></div></div>'
            },
         {
            displayName: 'Edit',
            cellTemplate: '<button id="editBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="edit(row)" >Modify</button> '

        }]
    };

});
```

Comment: thanks it is working as i wanted ,as i am a very beginner i am not getting what exactly you have done into my code and where i was wrong , nyways thanks for correcting it.

Comment: you are welcome please accept the answer,whati change in your code is changing cellTemplate in ng-grid definition to cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText"><div ng-show="!row.entity.edit">{{row.entity.yrs}}</div>' +
                '<div ng-show="row.entity.edit" class="ngCellText"><input type="text" ng-model="row.entity.yrs"/></div></div>'

Comment: @AnkitaSingh you are welcome ,in the left side of my answer on your screen there is an accept answer check, check this button please for me to get more reputation points thanks